# Why do I see "the temporary folder has not yet been created" message?

Tags: java, junit

In the following code I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: the temporary folder has not yet been created` at the `getRoot()` call.

I found a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844420/java-temporaryfolder-getroot-exception) according to which this code should work. Also, I noticed that if I add `temporaryFolder.create();` before the `getRoot()` call, the code works fine.

```java
    public class MainTest extends TestCase {
    
        @Rule
        public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
    
        @Test
        public void testMethod() throws Exception {
            File folder = temporaryFolder.getRoot();
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing JUnit 3 (junit.framework.*) and JUnit 4 (org.junit.*) code. The problem should disappear if you are using JUnit 4 only.

Remove `extends TestCase` (they are simple not needed, because your tests are annotated with `@Test`).